# Sharing RO data between Docker containers without copying it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have one Docker image `data-image` which contains about 80 GB of data at `/data`. I would like a container from another image `runner-image` to have read-only access to this data. The data is never modified.

The recommended way to share data between containers is [with a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). However [per the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted such as /app/, the directory’s contents are **copied** into the volume.

When I start a container which creates the volume:

```
docker run --volume data-volume:/data:ro data-image
```

the Docker daemon grinds to a halt because it is copying all of the data into the volume.

Once it eventually finishes, I can indeed see the data from the runner image:

```
 docker run --volume data-volume:/data:ro runner-image ls /data
```

This shows the data as expected, but the initial copy is slow and expensive. How can I avoid that?

(`data-image` is the image holding the data, `runner-image` is the image which would like access to the data, `data-volume` is the name of the volume created here - but maybe volumes are not the best choice here.)

Is it possible to for one container to share read-only data to another, without first copying it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please check the names used in your question. `runner-image` is only in the description and not in the command, while `data-volume` is only in the command and not in the description. It isn't clear how the identifiers map between the description and the command.

Comment: Sure, I expanded on my question for clarity.

Comment: The only way to share data between containers is via volumes. Your data should live *on the volume*, not in the image; it shouldn't be something that needs to be copied over at runtime. Populate the volume once, and then mount it wherever you need it.